# MySQL bulk insert joint tables

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I was wondering if it is possible to bulk insert data into database tables using a join query.

I.e. to make it easier matching foreign keys and primary keys, I would like to bulk insert all data for every table at one time. In the file I would be bulk inserting from, I would have all the fields of the table in the order in which they are joined.

Bulk loading each table individually seems really inefficient to me.

**Is this possible? Has it been done?**

Comment: I'm not sure I see the benefit of what you are suggesting.  The same amount of data has to be parsed/read in both cases, and sent to the database.  The database is the appropriate place for primary-foreign key relationships to be made, not outside.

Comment: It makes it easier for me to write up test data records. I would have to do it for each table individually if I didn't join the tables. We're making records to specifically test search functions, creation functions and whatnot, so are wanting to add records with specific data. Doing this seperately and keeping track of primary keys (account id's->profile Id's->address id's) is going to be very time consuming, so I was hoping there was a way I could do it in one file.

Comment: @chris how did u fixed it mate?

Comment: @Jay I don't think I found a solution to this. Sorry I can't help more.